# Call token function in my service contract

Tags: solidity

I want to charge a token value to perform a function within my contract.
I created the token in the mist, did the deploy on the private network and everything is running.

my code :

```
contract my_contract{    
    function my_function() public {
        do_something;
        // token other contract below
        token.transferFrom(msg_sender, to_address, amount); 
    }    
}
```

How exactly do I do this?
How do I instantiate a token in my contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the interface for the contract you want to call in your client contract and pass in the contract address when you deploy.

Example:
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

```
contract ERC20 {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);

  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract my_contract {
    ERC20 _token;

    function my_contract(address tokenAddress) public {
        _token = ERC20(tokenAddress);
    }

    function my_function(address to, uint amount) public {
        //do_something

        _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, amount);
    }
}
```